# HTML auto resizing banner to fit different formats/screens

Tags: html, banner

I've made a banner for my new webshop, but there is one problem.
When the website is in full size for example on my laptop, the banner fits perfect, but when i see the website on mobile, laptop and smaller size then banner isn't fitting.
I really hope that some of you could help me to get the banner auto fitting.

The HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bannersnack_embed = {"hash":"bxplv88nb","width":900,"height":297,"t":1425594057,"userId":17355456,"wmode":"transparent"};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://files.bannersnack.com/iframe/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try look into using different image formats for different screens and CSS @media queries. Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    /*Your CSS here*/
}
```

Also you might want to use responsive element with background image. Example:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51d44341e4b085686833bb66/520a9569e4b007829c46f58d/520a969be4b007829c473837/1378226922960/?format=1000w);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
```

Here is a good tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Im happy that you want to help, but i still can't get it to work. Ive tried to place my HTML code where you said.